# Cannot refer to the non-final local variable jSONString defined in an enclosing scope

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass JSON string to the server after 60 seconds. At the moment I am facing problem when I try to execute MyAsyncTask from an thread;  `jSONString` is not accessable at this line `new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);` and I am getting this error `Cannot refer to the non-final local variable jSONString defined in an enclosing scope`

This part of code is being called from the **onLocationChanged method in the inner class of the MainActivity**:

```
String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);
PostData sender = new PostData();
sender.timer(jSONString);
```

PostData class:

```
public class PostData {
    String jSONString;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public PostData() {
        super();
    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;
    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public void timer(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean run = true;
                while (run) {
                   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString); //How can I access this variable'jSONString' here?
                       }
                   }, 5000);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground " +params[0]);
            //the connection code.

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jSONString` which is declared in `PostData` currently trying to access `timer` method parameter which is not `final` :

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(PostData.this.jSONString);
```